# Killing Ozma WITHOUT Magic Hammer

Tags: final-fantasy-9

My friend dared me to kill Ozma without Quina's Magic Hammer, and I'm having quite a hard time doing so :( Any tips and tricks that might help?

Ps> I have a all items & all skills learned on all characters, max level and only the Iifa Tree endgame quest remaining.. no cheats, of course~

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you have to do is use **Eiko's Carbuncle summon**. It casts reflect on the entire party, which effectively trounces the effects of Ozma's Curse attack. Essentially, Curse is the major defining feature separating Ozma from other bosses. Once Curse is out of the way, the rest is fairly standard.

Note that casting reflect (or auto-reflect) on **each party member individually** is **not the same as Carbuncle's Ruby Light**. This individualized method will only lead to a quick and violent death, as Curse can pass through each single reflect spell.